# Algorithmic trading backtesting

Tags: python

I don't know if anyone is interested but I'll give it a chance. I have some basic experience in coding Python and would like to know if there are any suggestions on writing better code to improve myself.

There is no need to write the code for me, but if you guys have any tips on how to do it better that would be awesome. This script is an attempt on building a backtesting machinery for me to backtest some algorithmic trading strategies. It's made up of 3 files and although I tried to keep it clean, it doesn't look clean to me.

This is the main one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader as web
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
#from strategies import strategies
from scan import Scanner
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

scan = False
saveScan = True
showProgress = False
showPlot = False
long = True
short = True
perYear = False

plt.style.use('ggplot')
mpl.use('TkAgg')
resaults_list = []

souce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://stockmarketmba.com/listofetfsforanindexprovider.php?s=5')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(souce, 'lxml')
tickers = []

if scan:
    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        if "analyze.php?s=" in a['href'] and "/" not in a['href']:
            newticker = a['href'].replace("analyze.php?s=", "")
            tickers.append(newticker)
else:
    # Tickers = , 'FLGE', 'FLRG'
    tickers = ['FAS', 'REM']

start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()
rdelta = relativedelta(end, start)
rdelta = rdelta.years

for i in range(3):
    for ticker in tickers:
        df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
        df.drop(['High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Adj Close'], axis=1, inplace=True)

        #Opening the scanner with allt the inputs
        scanner = Scanner(df, ticker, scan, saveScan, showProgress, showPlot, long, short, resaults_list, i, rdelta, perYear)
        resaults_list = scanner.heart()

    #Loopling trough Long-Short, Long and Short
    if long:
        long = False
    elif short:
        long = True
        short = False

#Saving the results from the Dataframe to excel
if scan or saveScan:
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(resaults_list)
    df2.columns = ['Rev','LongShort','Ticker', 'Wallet Mean', 'Wallet', 'Wallet increase', 'Plus', 'Minus']
    #df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['Wallet'], ascending=False)
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    df2.to_excel(f'data/{now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M")}_scan.xlsx',
             index=False)
```

#### scan.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from strategies import strategies
import datetime as dt

class Scanner:
    def __init__(self, df, ticker, scan, saveScan, showProgress, showPlot, long, short, resaults_list, rev, rdelta, perYear):
        self.df = df
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.df = df
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.scan = scan
        self.saveScan = saveScan
        self.showProgress = showProgress
        self.showPlot = showPlot
        self.long = long
        self.short = short
        self.resaults_list = resaults_list
        self.rev = rev
        self.rdelta = rdelta
        self.perYear = perYear

    def heart(self):
        df = self.df
        ticker = self.ticker
        scan = self.scan
        saveScan = self.saveScan
        showProgress = self.showProgress
        showPlot = self.showPlot
        long = self.long
        short = self.short
        resaults_list = self.resaults_list
        rev = self.rev
        rdelta = self.rdelta
        perYear = self.perYear

        ema12 = df.Close.ewm(span=12, adjust=False).mean()
        ema26 = df.Close.ewm(span=26, adjust=False).mean()
        ema200 = df.Close.ewm(span=200, adjust=False).mean()
        macd = ema12 - ema26
        ema6 = macd.ewm(span=6, adjust=False).mean()

        df['macd'] = macd
        df['signal'] = ema6
        df['ema200'] = ema200
        increase = []
        olong = []
        clong = []
        oshort = []
        cshort = []
        wallet = []
        buyandhold = []

        bought = False
        sold = False
        longClose = 0
        shortClose = 0
        poss = 0
        neg = 0
        sell_possetive = 0
        wallet_increase = 0
        wallet_value = 1000
        buyandhold_wallet = 1000
        old_price = -1
        tomorrow = "tomt"

        for i in range(0, len(df)):

            strategie = strategies(df['macd'][i], df['signal'][i], df['Close'][i], df['ema200'][i], bought, sold)
            close = df['Close'][i]

            if tomorrow == "ol":
                longClose = df['Close'][i]
                increase.append(np.nan)
                olong.append(df['Close'][i])
                clong.append(np.nan)
                oshort.append(np.nan)
                cshort.append(np.nan)
                wallet.append(wallet_value)
                bought = True
                tomorrow = "tomt"

            elif tomorrow == "cl":
                increase.append(df['Close'][i] - longClose)
                olong.append(np.nan)
                clong.append(df['Close'][i])
                oshort.append(np.nan)
                cshort.append(np.nan)
                wallet_value = ((wallet_value / longClose) * df['Close'][i])
                wallet.append(wallet_value)
                bought = False
                tomorrow = "tomt"

                if df['Close'][i] - longClose > 0:
                    poss += 1
                elif df['Close'][i] - longClose < 0:
                    neg += 1

            elif tomorrow == "os":
                shortClose = df['Close'][i]
                increase.append(np.nan)
                oshort.append(df['Close'][i])
                cshort.append(np.nan)
                olong.append(np.nan)
                clong.append(np.nan)
                wallet.append(wallet_value)
                sold = True
                tomorrow = "tomt"

            elif tomorrow == "cs":
                increase.append(shortClose - df['Close'][i])
                cshort.append(df['Close'][i])
                oshort.append(np.nan)
                olong.append(np.nan)
                clong.append(np.nan)
                wallet_value = ((wallet_value / df['Close'][i]) * shortClose)
                wallet.append(wallet_value)
                sold = False
                tomorrow = "tomt"

                if df['Close'][i] - shortClose > 0:
                    poss += 1
                elif df['Close'][i] - shortClose < 0:
                    neg += 1

            else:
                increase.append(np.nan)
                oshort.append(np.nan)
                cshort.append(np.nan)
                olong.append(np.nan)
                clong.append(np.nan)
                wallet.append(wallet_value)

            if strategie.olongMacd() and long:
                tomorrow = "ol"

            elif strategie.clongMacd() and long:
                tomorrow = "cl"

            elif strategie.oshortMacd() and short:
                tomorrow = "os"

            elif strategie.cshortMacd() and short:
                tomorrow = "cs"

            if old_price < 0:
                old_price = df['Close'][i]

            buyandhold_wallet = (buyandhold_wallet / old_price) * df['Close'][i]
            buyandhold.append(buyandhold_wallet)
            old_price = df['Close'][i]

        df['increase'] = increase
        df['Open Long'] = olong
        df['Close Long'] = clong
        df['Open Short'] = oshort
        df['Close Short'] = cshort
        df['wallet'] = wallet
        df['buyandhold'] = buyandhold

        print(str(rev), "", ticker)
        if showProgress:
            print("Mean ", df['increase'].mean())
            print("Plus: ", poss)
            print("Minus: ", neg)

        longshort1 = ' Long ' if long else ''
        longshort2 = ' Short ' if short else ''
        wal_increase = ((df['wallet'].iloc[-1] - df['wallet'][0]) / df['wallet'][0]) * 100

        if perYear:
            resaults_list.append(["Y " + str(rev), longshort1 + longshort2, ticker, int(df['wallet'].mean()), int(df['wallet'].iloc[-1]), int(wal_increase / rdelta), int(poss / rdelta), int(neg / rdelta)])
        else:
            resaults_list.append(["T " + str(rev), longshort1 + longshort2, ticker, int(df['wallet'].mean()), int(df['wallet'].iloc[-1]), int(wal_increase), int(poss), int(neg)])

        if showPlot:
            ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((12, 1), (0, 0), rowspan=4, colspan=1, title=ticker)
            ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((12, 1), (5, 0), rowspan=4, colspan=1, title='Macd', sharex=ax1)
            ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((12, 1), (9, 0), rowspan=4, colspan=1, title='Wallet', sharex=ax1)

            ax1.plot(df.index, df['Close'], color='black', label='Close')
            ax1.plot(df.index, df['ema200'], color='blue', label='ema200')
            ax1.scatter(df.index, df['Open Long'], color='green', label='Open long', marker='^', alpha=1)
            ax1.scatter(df.index, df['Close Long'], color='red', label='Close long', marker='v', alpha=1)
            ax1.scatter(df.index, df['Open Short'], color='blue', label='Open short', marker='v', alpha=1)
            ax1.scatter(df.index, df['Close Short'], color='black', label='Close short', marker='^', alpha=1)
            ax1.legend(fontsize='x-small')

            ax2.plot(df.index, df['signal'], color='red', label='signal')
            ax2.plot(df.index, df['macd'], color='green', label='macd')
            ax2.axhline(0, linestyle='-.', color='black')
            ax2.legend(fontsize='x-small')

            ax3.plot(df.index, df['wallet'], color='red', label='wallet')
            ax3.plot(df.index, df['buyandhold'], color='green', label='Buy and hold')
            ax3.axhline(0, linestyle='-.', color='black')
            ax3.legend(fontsize='x-small')

            plt.show()

        if not scan:
            df.to_excel('data/{}.xlsx'.format(ticker), index=False)

        return resaults_list
```

#### strategies.py

```
class strategies():
    def __init__(self, macd, signal, close, ema200, bought, sold):
        self.macd = macd
        self.signal = signal
        self.close = close
        self.ema200 = ema200
        self.bought = bought
        self.sold = sold

    def olongMacd(self):
        s1 = self.macd > self.signal
        s2 = self.close > self.ema200
        s3 = 0 > self.macd
        s4 = not self.bought and not self.sold
        output = s1 and s2 and s3 and s4
        return output

    def clongMacd(self):
        s1 = self.signal > self.macd
        s2 = self.bought
        output = s1 and s2
        return output

    def oshortMacd(self):
        s1 = self.signal > self.macd
        s2 = self.ema200 > self.close
        s3 = self.macd > 0
        s4 = not self.bought and not self.sold
        output = s1 and s2 and s3 and s4
        return output

    def cshortMacd(self):
        s1 = self.macd > self.signal
        s2 = self.sold
        output = s1 and s2
        return output
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: I see you've edited the title - but it still doesn't say what the code _does_.  On Code Review, the title always states the purpose of the code - the implied question is always, "How can this be improved?" and it doesn't need stating.

Comment: Is the `for i in range(0, len(df)):` supposed to be part of the `heart(self)` method? I'm trying to recreate your original indentation (it's very important in Python), but I can't be certain about that part. It almost looks like there's a function definition missing.